# How to programmatically set a subview's frame to fit it inside its superview?

Tags: ios, view, frame, addsubview

I need to programmatically do the following. How can I do this? The code should be dynamic enough to fit a portrait view inside landscape also. The views are not UIImageViews.
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind including the `AVFoundation` framework in your project, you can use: `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(CGSize aspectRatio, CGRect boundingRect);`

Its documentation states:

> Returns a scaled CGRect that maintains the aspect ratio specified by a CGSize within a bounding CGRect.

It can be used as:

```
subview.frame = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(subview.bounds.size, superview.bounds);
```

**Parameters:**

> *aspectRatio*: The width and height ratio (aspect ratio) you want to maintain.
>
> *boundingRect*: The bounding rectangle you want to fit into.

Comment: What are the downsides of including AVFoundation framework? Some performance issues or..

Comment: No, shouldn't have any downside really @NerminSehic

Answer (score 0):

```
float ratio = subView.bounds.size.height/subView.bounds.size.width;

[subView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,superView.bounds.size.width,superView.bounds.size.width*ratio)];
[subView setCenter:CGPointMake(superView.bounds.size.width/2,superView.bounds.size.height/2)];
```

Comment: I liked the way you centered the view. But the way you set the frame is not dynamic, although it will work for the example.